# Highlight the currently selected menu (based on action+controller+routeValues)

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a menu for my MVC3 solution. In this menu, I have 2 kind of links:

- classic links based on action + controller

> Example 1: action = "Studies" + controller = "Main"
>
> Example 2: action = "Contact" + controller = "Main"

- a little more complex links based on action + controller + routeValues

> Example 3: action = "List" + controller = "Project" + routeValues =
> new { category = "BANK" }
>
> Example 4: action = "List" + controller = "Project" + routeValues =
> new { category = "PHARMA" }

The menu is displayed like this:

- Studies
- Contact
- Bank
- Pharma
- ...

I would like to select the currently active menu item based on the active page. To achieve this, I implement an htmlHelper like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionMenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        var route = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData;
        var controller = route.GetRequiredString("controller");
        var action = route.GetRequiredString("action");
    
        // some code here...

        if ((controller == controllerName) && (action == actionName))
        {
            tag.AddCssClass("active");
        }
        else
        {
            tag.AddCssClass("inactive");
        }

        // some code here...
    }
```

The problem with this basic implementation is that the condition to activate/inactivate menu item is based only on the action and controller values. I also need to check my routeValues for the "complex links" (example 3 & 4).

How can I implement this?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionMenuItem(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
{
    var route = htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData;
    var rvd = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(routeValues);

    // some code here...

    if (IsRouteValuesMatch(rvd, route))
    {
        tag.AddCssClass("active");
    }
    else
    {
        tag.AddCssClass("inactive");
    }

    // some code here...
}

private static bool IsRouteValuesMatch(RouteValueDictionary rvd, RouteData routeData)
{
    foreach (var item in rvd)
    {
        var value1 = item.Value as string;
        var value2 = routeData.Values[item.Key] as string;
        if (!string.Equals(value1, value2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```